# Why weka calculates wrong number function of stringToWordVector on WEKA?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, feature-extraction, text-classification

I want to calculate stringToWordVector of my dataset on WEKA application. I update parameter of wordsToKeep by 50. But It calculates 78 words. I want 50 words but it calculates 78 words. How can I correct the calculation?

My data set : http://www.dt.fee.unicamp.br/~tiago/smsspamcollection - Link1

Comment: please include the code you are using, otherwise it is hard to help

Comment: there is not code. WEKA is an application for data mining. http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html

Comment: No, WEKA is a library, which can be used both from code and through WEKA-GUI. If you use just a gui - then you should include exact actions you do before the error occures so we can easily reproduce it.

Comment: I get preprocess tab and I upload file of my data set in ".arff" format. After, I click filter choice and I select StringToWordVector. The function is setted and I click the raw. Editor of StringToWordVector opens. Choice of wordsToKeep is 1000 default. I set it 50. And I click apply button. Attribute panel has 78 att. But I set it 50. Why it is 78 att?

Answer (score 2):

`-W` option restricts number of words to keep **per class**, thus for 2 classes setting -W 50 gives you limit of a 100

from source:

```
public String wordsToKeepTipText() {
    return "The number of words (per class if there is a class attribute "+
    "assigned) to attempt to keep.";
  }
```

Furthermore, based on a [source](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/21712804/), it is not a strict constraint and it only affects where to prune the sorted occurences list, this can be altered

```
// sort the array
sortArray(array);
if (array.length < m_WordsToKeep) {
// if there aren't enough words, set the threshold to
// minFreq
prune[z] = m_minTermFreq;
  } else {
// otherwise set it to be at least minFreq
prune[z] = Math.max(m_minTermFreq, 
    array[array.length - m_WordsToKeep]);
  }
```